# Replace elements of a vector with different probability for 0 to 1, and 1 to 0 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, replace

Is there a possibility to replace the zeros in `A` by 1, and the 1's in `A` by 0 with fixed, but different probability?

For example:

`A = [0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0]` and I want to replace 0 by 1 with probability 1/4 and 1 by 0 with probability 1/3.

I'm trying something like this, but it doesn't work with the probability. My array here is `Sent`, which has 0's and 1's not uniformly distributed, but with certain probability (3/7th 0's and 4/7th 1's), which is captured in the `Sent` variable, but now I need to change it to `Received`, which has a different probability.

```
prob=3/7; 
n=100;
pdatodo=1/3;
pdotoda=1/4;
Sent=rand(n,1)>prob;
Received=Sent;
Sent(Received == 0) = 1>pdotoda; Sent(Received == 1) = 0>pdatodo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0]

%// first remember the positions of the orginal 1s and 0s
i0 = find(A==0); 
i1 = find(A==1);

p0to1 = 1/4;
p1to0 = 1/3;

%//Create the replacements vectors that will have the size of the original number of 0s and 1s respectively
r0to1 = rand(size(A(i0))) < p0to1;
r1to0 = rand(size(A(i1))) < p1to0

%//Put the replacement vectors in the correct indices (found at the start)
A(i0(r0to1)) = 1;
A(i1(r1to0)) = 0;
```

Comment: Why for `r0to1` you are comparing with `p1to0` and for `r1to0` with `p0to1`? If you set both probabilities to zero your code turns all elements to 1 while it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia sorry, typo. Fixed now.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia it was more than a typo actually, there were some other errors. but now it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0];
p1to0 = 1/3;
p0to1 = 1/4;

%// Find transition probability for each element
transitionProb = A*p1to0 + (1-A)*p0to1;

%// Flip the bits with corresponding ptransition probability
A = xor(A, rand(size(A)) < transitionProb);
```

You can test this by putting both probabilities to zero (expecting no change) and to one (expecting all bits being flipped).